# Orthogonality of Random Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, random-variables

Suppose I have 2 random vectors $U$ and $V$. I know that $U$ is perpendicular to $V$ with probability 1.

Does this imply $\mathbf{E}[U]^T\mathbf{E}[V]$ is $0$

Assume that the expectations exist and applying Fubini-Tonelli should suggest it to be true.
Am I missing something?

Comment: its not true in general, its very easy to give a counterexample, by example taking $U:=\mathbf{1}_{[0,1/2]}$ and $V:=\mathbf{1}_{(1/2,1]}$ in the probability space $[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure. However its true when $U$ and $V$ are independent

Comment: Do we really need independence?. Isnt almost sure enough?

Comment: I didnt get the example? How are these vectors? And how are they orthogonal?

Comment: no, independence is not needed in general, however independence ensures that $E[U\cdot  V]=E[U]\cdot E[V]$

Comment: The question is not really about scalars. It is about vectors. How do you define a multiplication of vectors

Comment: Rostader, here is a vectorized version of Masacroso's example.  With prob 1/2 let $U'=(1,0), V'=(0,1)$ and with prob 1/2 let $U'=(0,1), V'=(1,0)$. Then with probability 1, $U$ and $V$ are perpendicular.  But $E[U]=E[V]=(1/2,1/2)'$,  and so on.  Your "not really about" comment is wrong.

Comment: If they are perpendicular, then they are corrrelated, and their individual expectations do not reflect this.

Comment: @rostader an "scalar" is also a vector, that is, $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ 8and in general any field) are also vector spaces

Comment: @user619894 not necessary, take for example $U = (\xi, 0)$ and $V = (0, \eta)$ where $\xi$ and $\eta$ are non-degenerate independent.

Comment: @mihaild Good point, agreed, yet knowledge of orthogonality alone does not imply that this is the case